# Load data to few lists

Tags: c#, list, memory, windows-phone

```
       try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Reminders.xml", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Reminders>));
                    remind = (List<Reminders>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                    List2 = (List<Reminders>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
```

How to add the same data to the lists in this way without reading data from memory each time?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask - please update your question with more detail.

Comment: Do you want to remove the additional deserialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done with Linq in the following way.

```
remind = (List<Reminders>)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
List2 = remind.ToList();
```

Comment: Is there an error message? Did you include the following directive? `using System.Linq;`

Comment: There is no error, the list nothing is assigned. This is list2 : List<Reminders> List2 = new List<Reminders>();

Comment: Okay, it works. For some reason, the file is deleted, and therefore nothing being shown. It is possible that some bug.